# ¿Cómo aplicar la funcion json_encode a un arreglo?

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

Por alguna razón al intentar utilizar la funcion `json_encode()` en mi array aparece vacio.

Este es mi array:

```
(
    [page] => 1
    [total] => 1
    [records] => 43
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 0
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 24215 - CENTRO DE EDUCACION INTEGRADA DE ADULTOS
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => COMPRA DE ESTANTES Y OTROS.
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(0)"></span> - COMPRA DE 04 ESTANTES  DE... <span id="det0" class="oculto">- COMPRA DE 04 ESTANTES  DE MADERA DE 1.56X0.90 X 046 M
- UN ESTANTE DE MADERA CON  PUERTA DE VIDRIOS PARA BIBLIOTECA.</span>
                            [monto] => 618030
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 24215 - CENTRO DE EDUCACION INTEGRADA DE ADULTOS
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => COMPRA DE CORTINAS Y OTROS.
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(1)"></span> - 03 CORTINAS (PAÑOS) BEACH O... <span id="det1" class="oculto">- 03 CORTINAS (PAÑOS) BEACH O VERDE DE 1,90 X 1,20 M.
- CAÑERÍAS Y TRES SOPORTES
- UN VENTILADOR DE PEDESTAL, 3 EN 1
- UNA IMPRESORA CANON MULTIFUNCIONAL (PIKMAN E-471, REFERENCIA)</span>
                            [monto] => 162772
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 24215 - CENTRO DE EDUCACION INTEGRADA DE ADULTOS
                            [componente] => PARTICIPACIÓN DE LA COMUNIDAD EDUCATIVA
                            [nom_actividad] => SALIDA PEDAGÓGICA-RECREATIVA Y CULTURAL
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(2)"></span> - SALIDA  CON LOS ESTUDIANTES... <span id="det2" class="oculto">- SALIDA  CON LOS ESTUDIANTES Y PROFESORES DEL ESTABLECIMIENTO A LA RESERVA NACIONAL "RÍO SIMPSON"</span>
                            [monto] => 1016150
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 24220 - ESCUELA ANEXA INDEPENDENCIA
                            [componente] => INVERSIÓN DE RECURSOS PEDAGÓGICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES
                            [nom_actividad] => CAMPEONATOS DEPORTIVOS 
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(3)"></span> DESARROLLAR UN CAMPEONATO DE... <span id="det3" class="oculto">DESARROLLAR UN CAMPEONATO DE BABY FÚTBOL, TENIS DE MESA Y JUEGOS TÍPICOS (RAYUELA, TRUCO, ETC.), PROGRAMADO EN VARIAS FECHAS, DONDE LOS ALUMNOS SE ORGANICEN Y SE INTEGREN LOS TRES CURSOS. </span>
                            [monto] => 122827
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 24220 - ESCUELA ANEXA INDEPENDENCIA
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => RINCÓN PEDAGÓGICO, ARTÍSTICO Y CULTURAL
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(4)"></span> IMPLEMENTACIÓN DE UN ESPACIO... <span id="det4" class="oculto">IMPLEMENTACIÓN DE UN ESPACIO CONFORTABLE, EN EL QUE SE PUEDA DISPONER DE FORMA ORGANIZADA Y RESGUARDADA, EL MATERIAL A UTILIZAR. GENERAR EN ESTE ESPACIO, LA POSIBILIDAD DE ACCESO A LA EXPLORACIÓN Y USO DE INSTRUMENTOS MUSICALES, LECTURA, MATERIAL DE ENTRETENIMIENTO, ETC.</span>
                            [monto] => 996380
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 24240 - LICEO BICENTENARIO ALTOS DEL MACKAY
                            [componente] => INVERSIÓN DE RECURSOS PEDAGÓGICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES
                            [nom_actividad] => INSTALACIÓN DE CÁMARAS DE SEGURIDAD EN EL ESTABLECIMIENTO EDUCACIONAL.
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(5)"></span> CONTRATACIÓN DE EMPRESA... <span id="det5" class="oculto">CONTRATACIÓN DE EMPRESA EXTERNA PARA INSTALACIÓN DEL SISTEMA DE CÁMARAS</span>
                            [monto] => 5459379
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 24240 - LICEO BICENTENARIO ALTOS DEL MACKAY
                            [componente] => INVERSIÓN DE RECURSOS PEDAGÓGICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES
                            [nom_actividad] => JORNADAS DE REFLEXIÓN
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(6)"></span> EL EQUIPO DIRECTIVO EN PLENO... <span id="det6" class="oculto">EL EQUIPO DIRECTIVO EN PLENO REALIZA JORNADAS DE REFLEXIÓN POR NIVELES, PARA QUE EL ALUMNADO COMPRENDA EL APOYO QUE DA EL SISTEMA DE CÁMARAS A LA "SANA CONVIVENCIA" Y EL CUIDADO DE LOS APARATOS UNA VEZ INSTALADOS.</span>
                            [monto] => 0
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 24240 - LICEO BICENTENARIO ALTOS DEL MACKAY
                            [componente] => INVERSIÓN DE RECURSOS PEDAGÓGICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES
                            [nom_actividad] => MONITOREO DE CÁMARAS
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(7)"></span> SE REALIZA MONITOREO DE... <span id="det7" class="oculto">SE REALIZA MONITOREO DE IMÁGENES Y RESPECTIVA GRABACIÓN DE ÉSTAS PARA APOYAR LA SANA CONVIVENCIA Y DEJAR EN RESGUARDO EL LICEO EN HORARIO NOCTURNO Y FINES DE SEMANA.</span>
                            [monto] => 0
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8345 - LICEO JOSEFINA AGUIRRE MONTENEGRO
                            [componente] => INVERSIÓN DE RECURSOS PEDAGÓGICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES
                            [nom_actividad] => FORMULAR REMEDIALES  EFICIENTES ANTE HECHOS DISRUPTIVOS
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(8)"></span> FORMULAR REMEDIALES EFICIENT... <span id="det8" class="oculto">FORMULAR REMEDIALES EFICIENTES Y EFICACES ANTE HECHOS QUE AFECTEN LA SEGURIDAD Y LA SANA 
CONVIVENCIA. </span>
                            [monto] => 0
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8345 - LICEO JOSEFINA AGUIRRE MONTENEGRO
                            [componente] => INVERSIÓN DE RECURSOS PEDAGÓGICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES
                            [nom_actividad] => IMPLEMENTACIÓN DE  CIRCUITO CERRADO DE  TELEVISIÓN
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(9)"></span> ADQUISICIÓN E INSTALACIÓN®.. <span id="det9" class="oculto">ADQUISICIÓN E INSTALACIÓN DE CÁMARAS DE TELEVIGILANCIA EN ZONAS COMUNES, COMO PASILLOS, COMEDOR Y ESCALERAS.

</span>
                            [monto] => 2244598
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8345 - LICEO JOSEFINA AGUIRRE MONTENEGRO
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => INSTALACIÓN DE SISTEMA DE SOPORTE PARA TELÓN
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(10)"></span> INSTALACIÓN DE SISTEMA DE... <span id="det10" class="oculto">INSTALACIÓN DE SISTEMA DE POLEAS QUE PERMITA EL USO ADECUADO DEL TELÓN.
</span>
                            [monto] => 997835
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8345 - LICEO JOSEFINA AGUIRRE MONTENEGRO
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => RECAMBIO DE ARCOS DE FÚTBOL Y AROS DE BASKETBALL.
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(11)"></span> REEMPLAZO DE ARCOS DE FÚTBOL... <span id="det11" class="oculto">REEMPLAZO DE ARCOS DE FÚTBOL Y AROS DE BASKETBALL, QUE CUMPLAN CON LOS NUEVOS REQUISITOS DE SEGURIDAD Y QUE PERMITAN EVITAR POSIBLES ACCIDENTES.
</span>
                            [monto] => 845470
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8345 - LICEO JOSEFINA AGUIRRE MONTENEGRO
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => INSTALACIÓN DE NUEV O MOBILIARIO
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(12)"></span> COMPRA E INSTALACIÓN DE DOS... <span id="det12" class="oculto">COMPRA E INSTALACIÓN DE DOS SOFÁS PARA LA SALA DE PROFESORES.
</span>
                            [monto] => 798000
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 13
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8346 - ESCUELA VICTOR DOMINGO SILVA
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => CORTINAJES PARA NUESTRAS SALAS
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(13)"></span> IMPLEMENTAR SIETE SALAS DE... <span id="det13" class="oculto">IMPLEMENTAR SIETE SALAS DE CLASES DE 2º CICLO CON CORTINAS, VISILLOS Y SUS RESPECTIVOS SOPORTES.</span>
                            [monto] => 2600000
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8346 - ESCUELA VICTOR DOMINGO SILVA
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => ESTANTERÌA
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(14)"></span> ESTANTES ESCOLARES... <span id="det14" class="oculto">ESTANTES ESCOLARES CERTIFICADOS (ID: 1116614)</span>
                            [monto] => 1650000
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8346 - ESCUELA VICTOR DOMINGO SILVA
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => PINTURAS SALAS DE CLASES
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(15)"></span> PINTAR SIETE SALAS DE CLASES... <span id="det15" class="oculto">PINTAR SIETE SALAS DE CLASES DEL 2º CICLO.</span>
                            [monto] => 1183312
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 16
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8348 - ESCUELA BAQUEDANO
                            [componente] => INVERSIÓN DE RECURSOS PEDAGÓGICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES
                            [nom_actividad] => MI TALLER AUDIOVISUAL
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(16)"></span> IMPLEMENTAR UNA CASETA... <span id="det16" class="oculto">IMPLEMENTAR UNA CASETA AUDIOVISUAL EN DONDE LOS ALUMNOS PUEDAN INTERACTUAR, ELABORAR Y DIFUNDIR EL MATERIAL ELABORADO POR EL TALLER DE PERIODISMO.
SE ESTIMA UN UNIVERSO ESCOLAR DE 20 ALUMNOS PARTICIPANTES, Y LOS BENEFICIARIOS DIRECTOS ES LA TOTALIDAD DE LA COMUNIDAD EDUCATIVA</span>
                            [monto] => 2723633
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [17] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8348 - ESCUELA BAQUEDANO
                            [componente] => PARTICIPACIÓN DE LA COMUNIDAD EDUCATIVA
                            [nom_actividad] => CONOCIENDO MI REGIÓN
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(17)"></span> PROMOVER EL CONOCIMIENTO DE... <span id="det17" class="oculto">PROMOVER EL CONOCIMIENTO DE NUESTRO ENTORNO POR MEDIO DE VISITAS PEDAGÓGICAS AL MONUMENTO NATURAL DE "CAPILLA DE MÁRMOL", MEDIANTE LA MODALIDAD DE VISITAS PEDAGÓGICAS, DONDE PARTICIPARÁ UN GRUPO REPRESENTATIVO DE  DE SEGUNDO CICLO, ACOMPAÑADOS POR  ADULTOS DE LA COMUNIDAD EDUCATIVA.</span>
                            [monto] => 2000000
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [18] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 18
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8348 - ESCUELA BAQUEDANO
                            [componente] => PARTICIPACIÓN DE LA COMUNIDAD EDUCATIVA
                            [nom_actividad] => "AL AGUA BAQUEDANO"
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(18)"></span> PROMOVER ESPACIOS DE VIDA... <span id="det18" class="oculto">PROMOVER ESPACIOS DE VIDA SALUDABLE Y RECREACIÓN POR MEDIO DE LA PRACTICA DE LA NATACIÓN, INCLUYENDOLA COMO EJE DE LAS CLASES DE EDUCACIÓN FÍSICA.</span>
                            [monto] => 2000000
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [19] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 19
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8349 - ESCUELA PEDRO QUINTANA MANSILA
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => IMPLEMENTACION SALA DE TEATRO Y EXPRESIÓN ARTÍSTICA
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(19)"></span> ADQUIRIR LOS ELEMENTOS Y... <span id="det19" class="oculto">ADQUIRIR LOS ELEMENTOS Y MATERIALES NECESARIOS QUE PERMITAN EL FUNCIONAMIENTO ADECUADO DE LA ACTUAL SALA DE TEATRO LA CUAL ACOMPAÑA LAS CLASES DE LENGUAJE DESARROLLANDO DISTINTOS OBJETIVOS DEL CURRICULUM.</span>
                            [monto] => 1200000
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [20] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 20
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8349 - ESCUELA PEDRO QUINTANA MANSILA
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => IMPLEMENTACIÓN  PARA SALA DE PSICOMOTRICIDAD
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(20)"></span> ADQUIRIR CALEFACTORES PARA LA... <span id="det20" class="oculto">ADQUIRIR CALEFACTORES PARA LA SALA DE PSICOMOTRICIDAD QUE PERMITA QUE LOS ESTUDIANTES DESARROLLEN SUS CLASES EN UN AMBIENTE CÁLIDO Y FAVORABLE.</span>
                            [monto] => 400000
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )

            [21] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 21
                    [cell] => Array
                        (
                            [rbd] => 8349 - ESCUELA PEDRO QUINTANA MANSILA
                            [componente] => MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACIÓN Y RENOVACIÓN DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO
                            [nom_actividad] => HERMOSAMIENTO SALA DE CLASES
                            [dsc_actividad] => <span class="sprite s16 descripcion mt-3 mr-5" onclick="mostrarDetalleActividad(21)"></span> LAS SALAS DE CLASES DEBEN SER... <span id="det21" class="oculto">LAS SALAS DE CLASES DEBEN SER ESPACIOS QUE FAVOREZCAN LOS APRENDIZAJES, CÁLIDOS Y ARMONIOSOS. EL CORTINAJE JUEGA UN ROL FUNDAMENTAL NO SOLO PORQUE PERMITE QUE SE VEA EN MEJORES CONDICIONES SINO QUE ADEMAS PERMITE OSCURECER EL AMBIENTE CUANDO SE REQUIERE EN LOS MOMENTOS DE UTILIZAR MEDIOS TECNOLÓGICOS.</span>
                            [monto] => 3460222
                            [estado] => 0
                            [estado_edu] => 0
                            [estado_pla] => 0
                            [marca] => 
                            [observaciones] => 
                            [rechazo] => 
                            [recreo] => 
                            [aprobar] => -
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

Comment: estas en stackoverflow en español por favor traduce esta pregunta y con gusto te ayudaremos

Comment: en ingles te dan como 50 respuestas :c y no puedes aprovechar

Comment: haha, lo siento, tambien lo pregunté en inglés, me confundí

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el fragmento de código en el que intentas usar `json_encode` ?

Answer (score 2):

Existen herramientas en línea que convierten el resultado de `print_r` en JSON. Aunque, si tienes el código que generó el arreglo en `print_r` por ejemplo:

```
print_r($datos);
```

Obtendrías tu JSON haciendo:

```
$json=json_encode($datos);
```

Una de las herramientas mencionadas más arriba [es esta](https://www.nestforms.com/php-print_r-to-json-online).

Aunque a tu array le falta esto al principio: `Array  (` y esto al final: `)`. Si quieres probar tú mismo, pon tu array entre estos bloques en el enlace citado más arriba:

```
 Array
(
    ... aquí el array como lo presentas en la pregunta
)
```

El resultado es:

```
{
    "page": "1",
    "total": "1",
    "records": "43",
    "rows": [{
        "id": "0",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "24215 - CENTRO DE EDUCACION INTEGRADA DE ADULTOS",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "COMPRA DE ESTANTES Y OTROS.",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> - COMPRA DE 04 ESTANTES DE... - COMPRA DE 04 ESTANTES DE MADERA DE 1.56X0.90 X 046 M\r\n- UN ESTANTE DE MADERA CON PUERTA DE VIDRIOS PARA BIBLIOTECA.<\/span>",
            "monto": "618030",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "24215 - CENTRO DE EDUCACION INTEGRADA DE ADULTOS",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "COMPRA DE CORTINAS Y OTROS.",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> - 03 CORTINAS (PA\u00d1OS) BEACH O... - 03 CORTINAS (PA\u00d1OS) BEACH O VERDE DE 1,90 X 1,20 M.\r\n- CA\u00d1ER\u00cdAS Y TRES SOPORTES\r\n- UN VENTILADOR DE PEDESTAL, 3 EN 1\r\n- UNA IMPRESORA CANON MULTIFUNCIONAL (PIKMAN E-471, REFERENCIA)<\/span>",
            "monto": "162772",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "24215 - CENTRO DE EDUCACION INTEGRADA DE ADULTOS",
            "componente": "PARTICIPACI\u00d3N DE LA COMUNIDAD EDUCATIVA",
            "nom_actividad": "SALIDA PEDAG\u00d3GICA-RECREATIVA Y CULTURAL",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> - SALIDA CON LOS ESTUDIANTES... - SALIDA CON LOS ESTUDIANTES Y PROFESORES DEL ESTABLECIMIENTO A LA RESERVA NACIONAL \"R\u00cdO SIMPSON\"<\/span>",
            "monto": "1016150",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "24220 - ESCUELA ANEXA INDEPENDENCIA",
            "componente": "INVERSI\u00d3N DE RECURSOS PEDAG\u00d3GICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES",
            "nom_actividad": "CAMPEONATOS DEPORTIVOS",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> DESARROLLAR UN CAMPEONATO DE... DESARROLLAR UN CAMPEONATO DE BABY F\u00daTBOL, TENIS DE MESA Y JUEGOS T\u00cdPICOS (RAYUELA, TRUCO, ETC.), PROGRAMADO EN VARIAS FECHAS, DONDE LOS ALUMNOS SE ORGANICEN Y SE INTEGREN LOS TRES CURSOS. <\/span>",
            "monto": "122827",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "24220 - ESCUELA ANEXA INDEPENDENCIA",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "RINC\u00d3N PEDAG\u00d3GICO, ART\u00cdSTICO Y CULTURAL",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> IMPLEMENTACI\u00d3N DE UN ESPACIO... IMPLEMENTACI\u00d3N DE UN ESPACIO CONFORTABLE, EN EL QUE SE PUEDA DISPONER DE FORMA ORGANIZADA Y RESGUARDADA, EL MATERIAL A UTILIZAR. GENERAR EN ESTE ESPACIO, LA POSIBILIDAD DE ACCESO A LA EXPLORACI\u00d3N Y USO DE INSTRUMENTOS MUSICALES, LECTURA, MATERIAL DE ENTRETENIMIENTO, ETC.<\/span>",
            "monto": "996380",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "24240 - LICEO BICENTENARIO ALTOS DEL MACKAY",
            "componente": "INVERSI\u00d3N DE RECURSOS PEDAG\u00d3GICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES",
            "nom_actividad": "INSTALACI\u00d3N DE C\u00c1MARAS DE SEGURIDAD EN EL ESTABLECIMIENTO EDUCACIONAL.",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> CONTRATACI\u00d3N DE EMPRESA... CONTRATACI\u00d3N DE EMPRESA EXTERNA PARA INSTALACI\u00d3N DEL SISTEMA DE C\u00c1MARAS<\/span>",
            "monto": "5459379",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "6",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "24240 - LICEO BICENTENARIO ALTOS DEL MACKAY",
            "componente": "INVERSI\u00d3N DE RECURSOS PEDAG\u00d3GICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES",
            "nom_actividad": "JORNADAS DE REFLEXI\u00d3N",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> EL EQUIPO DIRECTIVO EN PLENO... EL EQUIPO DIRECTIVO EN PLENO REALIZA JORNADAS DE REFLEXI\u00d3N POR NIVELES, PARA QUE EL ALUMNADO COMPRENDA EL APOYO QUE DA EL SISTEMA DE C\u00c1MARAS A LA \"SANA CONVIVENCIA\" Y EL CUIDADO DE LOS APARATOS UNA VEZ INSTALADOS.<\/span>",
            "monto": "0",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "7",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "24240 - LICEO BICENTENARIO ALTOS DEL MACKAY",
            "componente": "INVERSI\u00d3N DE RECURSOS PEDAG\u00d3GICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES",
            "nom_actividad": "MONITOREO DE C\u00c1MARAS",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> SE REALIZA MONITOREO DE... SE REALIZA MONITOREO DE IM\u00c1GENES Y RESPECTIVA GRABACI\u00d3N DE \u00c9STAS PARA APOYAR LA SANA CONVIVENCIA Y DEJAR EN RESGUARDO EL LICEO EN HORARIO NOCTURNO Y FINES DE SEMANA.<\/span>",
            "monto": "0",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "8",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8345 - LICEO JOSEFINA AGUIRRE MONTENEGRO",
            "componente": "INVERSI\u00d3N DE RECURSOS PEDAG\u00d3GICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES",
            "nom_actividad": "FORMULAR REMEDIALES EFICIENTES ANTE HECHOS DISRUPTIVOS",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> FORMULAR REMEDIALES EFICIENT... FORMULAR REMEDIALES EFICIENTES Y EFICACES ANTE HECHOS QUE AFECTEN LA SEGURIDAD Y LA SANA \r\nCONVIVENCIA. <\/span>",
            "monto": "0",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "9",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8345 - LICEO JOSEFINA AGUIRRE MONTENEGRO",
            "componente": "INVERSI\u00d3N DE RECURSOS PEDAG\u00d3GICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES",
            "nom_actividad": "IMPLEMENTACI\u00d3N DE CIRCUITO CERRADO DE TELEVISI\u00d3N",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> ADQUISICI\u00d3N E INSTALACI\u00d3N\u00ae.. ADQUISICI\u00d3N E INSTALACI\u00d3N DE C\u00c1MARAS DE TELEVIGILANCIA EN ZONAS COMUNES, COMO PASILLOS, COMEDOR Y ESCALERAS.\r\n\r\n<\/span>",
            "monto": "2244598",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "10",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8345 - LICEO JOSEFINA AGUIRRE MONTENEGRO",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "INSTALACI\u00d3N DE SISTEMA DE SOPORTE PARA TEL\u00d3N",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> INSTALACI\u00d3N DE SISTEMA DE... INSTALACI\u00d3N DE SISTEMA DE POLEAS QUE PERMITA EL USO ADECUADO DEL TEL\u00d3N.\r\n<\/span>",
            "monto": "997835",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "11",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8345 - LICEO JOSEFINA AGUIRRE MONTENEGRO",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "RECAMBIO DE ARCOS DE F\u00daTBOL Y AROS DE BASKETBALL.",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> REEMPLAZO DE ARCOS DE F\u00daTBOL... REEMPLAZO DE ARCOS DE F\u00daTBOL Y AROS DE BASKETBALL, QUE CUMPLAN CON LOS NUEVOS REQUISITOS DE SEGURIDAD Y QUE PERMITAN EVITAR POSIBLES ACCIDENTES.\r\n<\/span>",
            "monto": "845470",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "12",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8345 - LICEO JOSEFINA AGUIRRE MONTENEGRO",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "INSTALACI\u00d3N DE NUEV O MOBILIARIO",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> COMPRA E INSTALACI\u00d3N DE DOS... COMPRA E INSTALACI\u00d3N DE DOS SOF\u00c1S PARA LA SALA DE PROFESORES.\r\n<\/span>",
            "monto": "798000",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "13",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8346 - ESCUELA VICTOR DOMINGO SILVA",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "CORTINAJES PARA NUESTRAS SALAS",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> IMPLEMENTAR SIETE SALAS DE... IMPLEMENTAR SIETE SALAS DE CLASES DE 2\u00ba CICLO CON CORTINAS, VISILLOS Y SUS RESPECTIVOS SOPORTES.<\/span>",
            "monto": "2600000",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "14",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8346 - ESCUELA VICTOR DOMINGO SILVA",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "ESTANTER\u00ccA",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> ESTANTES ESCOLARES... ESTANTES ESCOLARES CERTIFICADOS (ID: 1116614)<\/span>",
            "monto": "1650000",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "15",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8346 - ESCUELA VICTOR DOMINGO SILVA",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "PINTURAS SALAS DE CLASES",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> PINTAR SIETE SALAS DE CLASES... PINTAR SIETE SALAS DE CLASES DEL 2\u00ba CICLO.<\/span>",
            "monto": "1183312",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "16",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8348 - ESCUELA BAQUEDANO",
            "componente": "INVERSI\u00d3N DE RECURSOS PEDAG\u00d3GICOS Y APOYO A LOS ESTUDIANTES",
            "nom_actividad": "MI TALLER AUDIOVISUAL",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> IMPLEMENTAR UNA CASETA... IMPLEMENTAR UNA CASETA AUDIOVISUAL EN DONDE LOS ALUMNOS PUEDAN INTERACTUAR, ELABORAR Y DIFUNDIR EL MATERIAL ELABORADO POR EL TALLER DE PERIODISMO.\r\nSE ESTIMA UN UNIVERSO ESCOLAR DE 20 ALUMNOS PARTICIPANTES, Y LOS BENEFICIARIOS DIRECTOS ES LA TOTALIDAD DE LA COMUNIDAD EDUCATIVA<\/span>",
            "monto": "2723633",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "17",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8348 - ESCUELA BAQUEDANO",
            "componente": "PARTICIPACI\u00d3N DE LA COMUNIDAD EDUCATIVA",
            "nom_actividad": "CONOCIENDO MI REGI\u00d3N",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> PROMOVER EL CONOCIMIENTO DE... PROMOVER EL CONOCIMIENTO DE NUESTRO ENTORNO POR MEDIO DE VISITAS PEDAG\u00d3GICAS AL MONUMENTO NATURAL DE \"CAPILLA DE M\u00c1RMOL\", MEDIANTE LA MODALIDAD DE VISITAS PEDAG\u00d3GICAS, DONDE PARTICIPAR\u00c1 UN GRUPO REPRESENTATIVO DE DE SEGUNDO CICLO, ACOMPA\u00d1ADOS POR ADULTOS DE LA COMUNIDAD EDUCATIVA.<\/span>",
            "monto": "2000000",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "18",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8348 - ESCUELA BAQUEDANO",
            "componente": "PARTICIPACI\u00d3N DE LA COMUNIDAD EDUCATIVA",
            "nom_actividad": "\"AL AGUA BAQUEDANO\"",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> PROMOVER ESPACIOS DE VIDA... PROMOVER ESPACIOS DE VIDA SALUDABLE Y RECREACI\u00d3N POR MEDIO DE LA PRACTICA DE LA NATACI\u00d3N, INCLUYENDOLA COMO EJE DE LAS CLASES DE EDUCACI\u00d3N F\u00cdSICA.<\/span>",
            "monto": "2000000",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "19",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8349 - ESCUELA PEDRO QUINTANA MANSILA",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "IMPLEMENTACION SALA DE TEATRO Y EXPRESI\u00d3N ART\u00cdSTICA",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> ADQUIRIR LOS ELEMENTOS Y... ADQUIRIR LOS ELEMENTOS Y MATERIALES NECESARIOS QUE PERMITAN EL FUNCIONAMIENTO ADECUADO DE LA ACTUAL SALA DE TEATRO LA CUAL ACOMPA\u00d1A LAS CLASES DE LENGUAJE DESARROLLANDO DISTINTOS OBJETIVOS DEL CURRICULUM.<\/span>",
            "monto": "1200000",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "20",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8349 - ESCUELA PEDRO QUINTANA MANSILA",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "IMPLEMENTACI\u00d3N PARA SALA DE PSICOMOTRICIDAD",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> ADQUIRIR CALEFACTORES PARA LA... ADQUIRIR CALEFACTORES PARA LA SALA DE PSICOMOTRICIDAD QUE PERMITA QUE LOS ESTUDIANTES DESARROLLEN SUS CLASES EN UN AMBIENTE C\u00c1LIDO Y FAVORABLE.<\/span>",
            "monto": "400000",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "21",
        "cell": {
            "rbd": "8349 - ESCUELA PEDRO QUINTANA MANSILA",
            "componente": "MEJORAMIENTO, ACTUALIZACI\u00d3N Y RENOVACI\u00d3N DE EQUIPAMIENTO Y MOBILIARIO",
            "nom_actividad": "HERMOSAMIENTO SALA DE CLASES",
            "dsc_actividad": "<\/span> LAS SALAS DE CLASES DEBEN SER... LAS SALAS DE CLASES DEBEN SER ESPACIOS QUE FAVOREZCAN LOS APRENDIZAJES, C\u00c1LIDOS Y ARMONIOSOS. EL CORTINAJE JUEGA UN ROL FUNDAMENTAL NO SOLO PORQUE PERMITE QUE SE VEA EN MEJORES CONDICIONES SINO QUE ADEMAS PERMITE OSCURECER EL AMBIENTE CUANDO SE REQUIERE EN LOS MOMENTOS DE UTILIZAR MEDIOS TECNOL\u00d3GICOS.<\/span>",
            "monto": "3460222",
            "estado": "0",
            "estado_edu": "0",
            "estado_pla": "0",
            "marca": "",
            "observaciones": "",
            "rechazo": "",
            "recreo": "",
            "aprobar": "-\r\n)"
        }
    }]
}
```